# How do I use imagesLoaded?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to trigger an action on a web page I have created once a (new) image has been loaded. The page basically displays a list of thumbnails, and whenever the user clicks a thumbnail, the larger corresponding image should be shown on the page. I want to fade the previous image out and the new one in.

What I first tried was this:

```
<div class="image-area" id="image-area">
  <img id="image-object" src="images/p01.jpg" width="auto" height="auto">
</div>

function SetImageFromSrc (s) {
  var imgArea = $("#image-area"); // the enclosing div
  var imgElem = $("#image-object"); // the img
  $.when (imgArea.fadeTo (imageFadeTime, 0)).done (function () {
    imgElem.attr ('src', s);
    imgElem.load (function() {
      imgArea.fadeTo (imageFadeTime, 1);
    });
  });
}
```

I know now that jQuery .load() doesn't always work, and it doesn't for me. In my case it doesn't even seem to work when the image is not already in the browser cache.

So I tried imagesLoaded, but I have no idea how to use it for a single image and how to wait until that image has loaded and then perform that action (fade the div containing the image in). The code I tried was as follows:

```
$('#image-area').imagesLoaded (function () {
  $(this).fadeTo (imageFadeTime, 1);
});
```

But it doesn't work. Apparently it doesn't even get invoked (I set a breakpoint using Google Chrome's developer tools inside of it).

So can anybody show me how to code this please?

Comment: Is your imagesLoaded code wrapped in a `$( document ).ready(function() {}` ?Because if not it may looking for an element before it exists and that's why it fails to fire.

Comment: No, it wasn't. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: As a general rule you should be keeping any element selection within a `$(document).ready()` or similar, or your selectors may fail.

Comment: Isn't `$` the short-form for `$(document).ready()`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

> $(document).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready.

```
// Shorthand for $( document ).ready()
$(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

> $(window).on("load", function() { ... }) will run once the entire page
>       (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

```
$(window).on("load", function() {
    console.log("window loaded");
});
```

http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: The problem is that once the page has been loaded, the user can make the images change, as often as he choses to. So whenever a thumbnail is clicked, the currently displayed big image should be faded out and the new one faded in. It won't just happen once.

You can check the behaviour here: brockart.de/new

Click on "Gemälde", then click on a few images in the thumbnail list appearing to the left of the page.